# onclick create random rectangle in canvas that won't collide with existing ones

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am super stuck on this, what i have done so far is I created function that creates random sized rectanges, which appears in a random place of the canvas. What i need to do is using JS draw Rectangle whenever I create new one, it can't collide with existing ones.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>rectangles sucks</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="buttonxD">press me!</button>
<script>
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.width = 500;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    body.appendChild(canvas);
function create() {
    //  Opacity
        context.globalAlpha=0.7;
        var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
        context.fillStyle = color;

        //Each rectangle's size is (20 ~ 100, 20 ~ 100)     
        context.fillRect(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*80+20, Math.random()*80+20);

}
     document.getElementById('buttonxD').addEventListener('click', create);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I seen that this function is used to check collision detection

```
  function isCollide(a, b) {
    return !(
        ((a.y + a.height) < (b.y)) ||
        (a.y > (b.y + b.height)) ||
        ((a.x + a.width) < b.x) ||
        (a.x > (b.x + b.width))
    );
}
```

But I failing to integrate it to my code...
Any ideas what I should do differently with my existing code, anything will help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to keep the coords from the existing rectangles. So you can check against that list if your new rectangle does not collide with one of them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>rectangles sucks</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button id="buttonxD">press me!</button>
    <script>
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = 500;
        canvas.width = 500;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        body.appendChild(canvas);

        var rects = [];

        function create() {
            //  Opacity
            context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
            var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
            context.fillStyle = color;

            //Each rectangle's size is (20 ~ 100, 20 ~ 100)
            var coordx = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            var coordy = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            var width = Math.random() * 80 + 20;
            var height = Math.random() * 80 + 20;

            var rect = {
                x: coordx,
                y: coordy,
                w: width,
                h: height
            }

            var ok = true;
            rects.forEach(function (item) {
                if (isCollide(rect, item)) {
                    console.log("collide");
                    ok = false;
                } else {
                    console.log("no collision");
                }
            })

            if (ok) {
                context.fillRect(coordx, coordy, width, height);
                rects.push(rect);
            } else {
                console.log('rect dropped');
            }

            console.log(rects);

        }

        function isCollide(a, b) {
            return !(
                ((a.y + a.h) < (b.y)) ||
                (a.y > (b.y + b.h)) ||
                ((a.x + a.w) < b.x) ||
                (a.x > (b.x + b.w))
            );
        }
        document.getElementById('buttonxD').addEventListener('click', create);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This only creates a rectangle if it does not collide.